# Adding watermark using XML:FO or XML Transform

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to add watermark using XML:FO or XML Transform. Watermark is text does anybody done this. Please let me know.

Thank you.

Regards,
Mona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an image to the page background by using `background-image=` on `<region-body>`.

It has to be done as an image ... XSL-FO does not support rendering text as a background.

For some XSL-FO processors you can mimic horizontal text as a watermark by overlapping a perimeter region with the body region and writing out your text in the perimeter region, but in some ways it is a violation of the specification that is ignored by those processors.  And there are nuances in under-specification of the specification that may end up putting your overlapping perimeter region on top of your body region, thus obscuring your main content.

So, really, a page background image is the best you can do with XSL-FO 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had to do this today. My solution was to use the background-image= and make it a dataurl of an image I had edited to make it pale.

Example, If you wanted VOID on a cheque then just write VOID in word, take a snapshot image of that word. Save as a jpg. Use editing software to make the text pale. Create a dataurl of the image and make that the background-image.

The poor mans watermark ;)